# Notepad ++ shows html code in red

Tags: notepad++, code-formatting

I have the following code:

```
... <?php echo '<button class="deleteSuperSub" sub="allmus"> - lösch<button>
</li>'; } ?> </ul><br><br>
```

my Code is a mix of php and html. After the closing tag of php(?>), the html is shown in read. But I want to see the html well highlighted which works in general. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which Syntax Highlighter are you using? HTML's or PHP's? (you can check it from the *Language* menu)

Comment: Sometimes I get this beaviour when I do a compare between two files. I just change the language to anyone then revert to the proper one and the syntax highlight is OK.

Comment: When I change the language in language menu to html, it works. Changing it to php also worked. Notepad pp does not seem to show in which language I am actually but it is probably not so important.On my php code, I have four languages in use(html, css, js and php), so this might be the reason why npp does not decide for one language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above:

> Sometimes I get this behaviour when I do a comparison between two files. I just change the language to any one, then revert to the proper one and the syntax highlighting is OK.
>
> When I change the language in the language menu to HTML, it works. Changing it to PHP also worked.